# How to eliminate duplicate XML namespace definitions?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I often come across XML where the same namespace is defined multiple times, instead of only at a parent element of the elements where it is needed.

Is there a simple method/tool for extracting all namespace definitions in an XML and relocating each of these definitions to a node such that each namespace is defined only once? Preferably also with an option for all nodes to be prefixed with their namespace (rather than using a default namespace from some parent). I find this would yield more human readable XML.

As an example, how could one automatically translate this

```
<m:Albums xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/music">
  <m:Album xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/music">
    <m:Artist xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/music">
      <c:Name xmlns:c="http://www.example.com/common">
        Sting
      </c:Name>
    </m:Artist>
    <m:Title>
      Mercury Falling
    </m:Title>
  </m:Album>
  <Album xmlns="http://www.example.com/music">
    <Artist>
      <c:Name xmlns:c="http://www.example.com/common">
        Maria Mena
      </c:Name>
    </Artist>
    <Title xmlns="http://www.example.com/music">
      Weapon in Mind
    </Title>
  </Album>
</m:Albums>
```

into this?

```
<m:Albums xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/music" xmlns:c="http://www.example.com/common">
  <m:Album>
    <m:Artist>
      <c:Name>
        Sting
      </c:Name>
    </m:Artist>
    <m:Title>
      Mercury Falling
    </m:Title>
  </m:Album>
  <m:Album>
    <m:Artist>
      <c:Name>
        Maria Mena
      </c:Name>
    </m:Artist>
    <m:Title>
      Weapon in Mind
    </m:Title>
  </m:Album>
</m:Albums>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As yet a better answer to my own question, I stumbled across [this external XSLT transformation](http://lenzconsulting.com/namespace-normalizer/normalize-namespaces.xsl) (EDIT: [XSLT 2.0 version](https://github.com/evanlenz/namespace-normalizer/blob/master/normalize-namespaces.xsl)), which does exactly what I wanted.

The result from transforming the question's input XML using this XSLT with Saxon:

```
<m:Albums xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/music" xmlns:c="http://www.example.com/common">
  <m:Album>
    <m:Artist>
      <c:Name>
        Sting
      </c:Name>
    </m:Artist>
    <m:Title>
      Mercury Falling
    </m:Title>
  </m:Album>
  <m:Album>
    <m:Artist>
      <c:Name>
        Maria Mena
      </c:Name>
    </m:Artist>
    <m:Title>
      Weapon in Mind
    </m:Title>
  </m:Album>
</m:Albums>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a partial answer to my own question I found that the unix command

```
xmllint --nsclean
```

partially solves the problem, but it does not eliminate all duplicate namespaces. When applied to my example XML from the question, it yields the following.

```
<m:Albums xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/music">
  <m:Album>
    <m:Artist>
      <c:Name xmlns:c="http://www.example.com/common">
        Sting
      </c:Name>
    </m:Artist>
    <m:Title>
      Mercury Falling
    </m:Title>
  </m:Album>
  <Album xmlns="http://www.example.com/music">
    <Artist>
      <c:Name xmlns:c="http://www.example.com/common">
        Maria Mena
      </c:Name>
    </Artist>
    <Title>
      Weapon in Mind
    </Title>
  </Album>
</m:Albums>
```

This eliminates namespaces already declared in a parent node. However, it does not pull duplicate namespace declarations up to a common parent (e.g. the `c:Name` nodes), nor does it remove a duplicate default namespace by converting the affected nodes to use an equivalent non-default namespace (e.g. the `Album` node in the default namespace, and its children).

Still hoping for a solution which can remove duplicate namespaces also in the cases where `xmllint` fails.

Comment: The trouble is that in-scope namespace declarations form part of the document infoset, so the transformation you're looking for actually changes the semantics of the document - you're changing the qualified name of a number of nodes (though not their local name or namespace URI) and introducing new namespace bindings on nodes where they weren't in scope before (e.g. the `c` prefix on the root element).

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't make too much difference but there's no 100% generic way to do this - how do you want to deal with situations where the same prefix is mapped differently in different places?  Or a document that uses the prefix mappings for something other than element names (e.g. `xsi:type="..."` where the _value_ of the attribute depends on the prefixes in scope on the corresponding element)?